# Stability of the equilibrium states

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I have a function defined by the following differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma - F(\varphi)
$$
where

- $F(\varphi)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function) and
- the chart of the function $F(\varphi)$ is known.

I need to find the equilibrium states (e.s.) and find out if they are stable. I've managed to find out what are they only in some cases (but this is not accurate). Can you help with others?

```
                 ^ F(φ)
                1|
                 |    /\  /\
                b|   /  \/  \
                 |  /        \
                 | /          \    
__-π_______-a____|/____________\____>φ
   \            /|0    a π/2   π 
    \          / |
     \        /  |
      \  /\  /   |-b
       \/  \/    |
                 |-1
```

If $|\gamma| > 1$ then there are no e.s.

If $|\gamma| = 1$ there are 2 (at level ±γ each) e.s. in points (a,1), (π-a,1). maybe they're semi-stable?

If $b < |\gamma| < 1$ there are $4$ at level $\pm \gamma$ each e.s.

If $|\gamma| = b$ there are $3$ at level $\pm\gamma$ each e.s.: point $(\pi/2, b)$, $\varphi = a\gamma$, $\gamma = \pi - a\gamma$.

If $0 < |\gamma| < b$ there are $2$ e.s. at level $\pm±\gamma$ each $\varphi  = a\gamma$ (is it stable?) , $\varphi = \pi - a\gamma$ (and is this one unstable?).

The form of $F(\varphi)$ is the following one:
$$F(\varphi)=\begin{cases}
 & {-\dfrac{\varphi}{a}-\dfrac{\pi}{a}},  &\text{if } {\varphi \in [-\pi, -\pi + a]},\\
\\
 & \dfrac{1-b}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }\varphi + \dfrac{(1-b)(\pi-a))}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }-1, &\text{if } {\varphi \in [-\pi + a,-\frac{\pi }{2}}], \\ 
\\
 & \dfrac{b-1}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }\varphi + \dfrac{a(1-b)}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }-1, &\text{if } {\varphi \in [-\dfrac{\pi }{2}}, -a], \\
\\
 & \dfrac{\varphi}{a},  &\text{if }  {\varphi \in [- a,  a]}, \\
\\
& \dfrac{b-1}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }\varphi - \dfrac{a(1-b)}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }+1, &\text{if } {\varphi \in [a, \frac{\pi }{2}}], \\
\\
& \dfrac{1-b}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }\varphi - \dfrac{(1-b)(\pi-a))}{\dfrac{\pi }{2}-a }+1, &\text{if } {\varphi \in [\frac{\pi }{2}}, \pi-a], \\ 
\\
 & {-\dfrac{\varphi}{a}+\dfrac{\pi}{a}},&\text{if }  {\varphi \in [\pi-a, \pi]}.
\end{cases}$$
P.S. sorry for this chart :)

Comment: To be honest, this ASCII chart impresses me a lot.

Comment: Please check for typos, the first case should be $>1$, then the 3-point case is where $|γ|=b$. You missed to include the case of negative $γ$ in some way, even just citing the symmetry. You also did not mention the consequences of the periodicity of the function.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks for noticing the typos! :) Should I write 4 points instead of 2? 8 instead of 4 and so on? Or how it'd be better? And could you also tell me what consequences of the periodicity should be mentioned?

Comment: If $φ_*$ is an equilibrium point, then also $φ_*+2k\pi$ are equilibrium points for the same $γ$. // You could also say $2$ at level $\pmγ$ each.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to solve the equation $$\gamma - F(\phi^*)=0$$ with the unknown $\phi^*\in\mathbb R$. Correct?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch exactly so! And also to find out the stability of the results obtained.

Comment: @nick Well the function is piecewise linear so you'll just have to look at it case-by-case in the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, and then look at $F'$ case-by-case. (And hope that there is no equilibrium at a point where $F$ is not differentiable.) Looks like a lot of "Fleissarbeit" (I don't know a good english word for it) to me. Once you are done, since the function is periodic, the situation will be identical on any $[-\pi+2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi], k\in\mathbb Z$.